# How to avoid unnecessary re-render of a component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, rerender

I have this case:

```
const Parent = () => {
  
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  
  return <>
    <Child1 value={value} />
    <Child2 setValue={setValue} />
    </>
  
}
```

but every time `setValue` of `Child2` is getting called, `Child2` re-renders although its props have not been changed (Child1 re-renders also, but this is the expected behavior since prop `value` changed).

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React `useState` state updater functions are guaranteed to be stable references, so `Child2` is only rerendering because the parent component `Parent` is rerendering due to the state update. If you want to hint to React that it can likely bail on rerendering a child component then use the [memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) Higher Order Component.

```
const Child2 = ({ setValue }) => {
  ....
};

export default memo(Child2);
```

### Demo

Demonstrates 2 "instances" of Child 2, one decorated with the `memo` HOC and the other not. All children use an `useEffect` to log when they are rendered. Note that all initially render, but only child 1 and 2 (w/o memo) continually are rerendered.

[image: Edit how-to-avoid-unnecessary-re-render-of-a-component-in-react]

Sandbox code:

```
import { memo, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Child1 = ({ value }) => {
  useEffect(() => console.log("Child 1 rendered"));
  return <div>Child1: {value}</div>;
};

const Child2 = ({ id, setValue }) => {
  useEffect(() => console.log(`${id} rendered`));
  return (
    <div>
      {id}: <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Child2wMemo = memo(Child2);

const Parent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <Child1 value={value} />
      <Child2 id="Child 2" setValue={setValue} />
      <Child2wMemo id="Child 2 with Memo" setValue={setValue} />
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Parent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is the purpose of [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) or [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo).

Example

```
const Parent = () => {
  
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const child2 = useMemo(() => <Child2 setValue={setValue} />, [setValue])
  
  return <>
    <Child1 value={value} />
    {child2}
    </>
  
}
```

`[setValue]` Is the dependencies array. Changes to anything in this array will cause the value to be re-calculated.

The reason it re-renders even though the props don't change is because you are changing state on the Parent component. This causes the Parent component to re-render, which will re-render all of the children regardless of whether their props change.

Alternatively, you could use React.memo on the child component like this:

```
const Child2 = React.memo(function Child2(props) {
  /* ... */
});
```